# Reserved CPU Time in Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a question regarding the *reserved CPU time* field in Google Dataflow. I don't understand why it varies so widely depending on the configuration of my run. I suspect that I am not interpreting the *reserved CPU time* for what it really is. To my understanding, it is the CPU time that was needed to complete the job I submitted, but based on the following evidence, it seems I may be mistaken. Is it the time that is allocated to your job, regardless of whether it is actually using the resources? If that's the case, how do I get the actual CPU time of my job?

First I ran my job with a variable sized pool of workers (max 24 workers). [image: Long run config]

The corresponding stats are as follows:

[image: Long run stats]

Then, I ran my script using a fixed number of workers (10):

[image: Short run config]

And the stats changes to:

[image: Short run stats]

They went from 15 **days** to 7 **hours**? How is that possible?!

Thanks!

Comment: In the log above for the first job mentioned I see that autoscaling is enabled '[sic] between 1 and 1000 worker...'.  Would you mind sending us the job ID so we can investigate further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hover over the "?" next to "Reserved CPU time" a pop-up message will show and it will read: "The total time Dataflow was active on GCE instances, on a per-CPU basis."  This indicates it is not the CPU-time used by the VMs.  At this time Dataflow does not aggregate per-machine CPU usage stats; you may, however, be able to use the [cloud monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics) to extract those metrics yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I had read the message, hovering over the "?", but I didn't understand the implications... Thanks for the clarification.